# In Python write list in two column in csv

Tags: python, csv

if I have two list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
```

and I want to write this in a csv file in two different columns through python. Like

```
ABC  BCA
1    1
2    2
3    3
4   
5
```

I know we have `zip`, `zip_longest` etc facilities, that zip these list and write in csv through `writerow()`. But do we have some direct way we can write in one column first then in second column(from top to bottom) like we do for row with `writerow` or `writerows`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service. Also, there isn't. It is very inefficient and more roundabout than just zipping them.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you , I am new in this tool (stackoverflow)  and not sure how this works.

Comment: Files can't be written column by column, you have to write the data in the order that it appears in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have two lists of columns. When writing to a file you need to work with rows. There is no way to write to a file a column at a time.

Secondly, as you point out, your two columns have different lengths. A well known trick is to use `zip(*my_list)`, which has the effect of transposing your lists, i.e. swapping rows/columns. By using `izip_longest()` it will automatically pad the second column.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['ABC', 'BCA'])
    csv_output.writerows(izip_longest(*[a, b]))
```

Giving you a CSV output file:

```
ABC,BCA
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,
5,
```

If you were to:

```
print list(izip_longest(*[a, b]))
```

You would see the effect it has on your data:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, None), (5, None)]
```

It is now in a form that can be written to your output file using the standard `.writerows()` call.